# Who is this actor/character in this "The Big Bang Theory" cast photo?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

I stumbled upon this photo of "The Big Bang Theory" cast:

[image: The Big Bang Theory]

I recognize all of the cast, except the actor highlighted in the white block.

He somewhat looks like the character of Dale, from Stewart's comic book store, played by [Josh Brener](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Josh_Brener).

But I'm not certain, and it seems odd that his character would be included with the other, more prominent, cast members. The time line doesn't fit either, as his episodes were in Season 5/6 vs
Rati Gupta (Anu) from Season 12.

Am I correct, or is this another character/actor?

Comment: This was closed as an identification question, but I don't think this fits the category. OP is well aware of the property and wants to know the name of a specific cast member.

Comment: I specifically checked the site tour before posting. It only prohibits "Identifying or locating a Movie or TV series", so I believed the question to be on-topic in good faith.

Comment: It'll be open again shortly, looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it shortly after posting.

It's the character of [Mitch](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Mitch), Stewart's girlfriend Denise's "creepy" roommate - played by [Todd Giebenhain](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm0317315/).

I assume it was taken after the episode in which he guest-starred.